# How to add a background picture to the JMenu Screen?

Tags: java, swing, image, jmenu

so I was wondering if there is anyway to add a picture as a background for the jmenu and by that I don't mean the JMenu bar but the actual screen below it.  I have looked online for a long time and can't seem to find any solution to my problem.  Any help/solution would be greatly appreciated.  Once again, I am trying to find a way to print a picture not on the JMenu bar, but the space that is below it.

Comment: agreed with post by @Mr. Polywhirl +1 but issue will be little bit complicated, for real and nice output and with readable text in JMenuItem could be required to play with UIManager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Once again, I am trying to find a way to print a picture not on the JMenu bar, but the space that 
>   is below it.

I think you mean the `content pane`. See [Using Top Level Containers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) to learn some of the terminology.

If this is what you mean then check out [Background Panel](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/background-panel/).

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you mean the `JMenuItem`? There is a [post on DreamInCode.net](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/205525-jmenuitem-background/) which discusses adding an image to a `JMenuItem`. All you have to do is extend the `JMenuItem` and override its `paintComponent()` method.

Solution by [*Dogstopper*](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/user/97990-dogstopper/):

```
public CustomMenuItem(){
        this.setOpaque(true);
        i = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Img/BackGround.png")).getImage();
        System.out.println(i);
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(i, 0, 0, this);

}
```